# Angular formControlName print error, wrong format

Tags: angular, pipe, form-control

Good day community,

Currently I have the following problem when passing an input value through a pipe, it is assigning the value as it should be, but when I use the formcontrol and try to print the value, it does not print it correctly.

Can someone explain to me why this could happen?

I share the problem that is presented in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ub1rhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fnumber.pipe.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[print error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bazha.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same `pipe` in your ts file to achieve the desired result.

I have updated your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n8mk2d?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hi @CodeWarrior, just modified the stackblitz, I would like to answer three questions

1. If I save to the database, would I first have to modify the num control by running the pipe again and using a pathValue?

2. Add an example of addition, TypeScript recognizes dotted decimals, so I have to change it before operating it, is the way I do it right?

3. Is there a way where the values ​​are only displayed at save time in the save form as it should be to avoid the above operations?

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aedxzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Hi @damanchola if I answered this question, please mark it as accepted and ask your queries separately in a new question. Also, post the link as comment here so that I can have a look.

Comment: Hi @CodeWarrior, of course, if your answer answered my question, I have left the questions in a different post, I will share it with you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889401/questions-about-formarray-and-pipe-when-operating-numbers