# Questions about formarray and pipe when operating numbers

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, formarray

I would like to answer three questions, according to the following code,
Well, I am using pipes and formarray to send them to the database and that the numbers are displayed in a correct format, then I leave the example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aedxzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

1. If I save to the database, would I have to first modify the array by running the pipe again and using a pathValue to modify the values?
2. Add an example of addition I see it necessary to modify the values ​​because TypeScript recognizes decimals as points, so I have to change it before operating it, is the way I do it correct?
3. Is there a way in which the values ​​are only displayed in the format that the pipe generates but when using the form control it saves them as number?

Currently I am trying to modify the arrangement by replacing the points with commas and the points with empties to operate them, it worked but I don't know if it is correct

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve in the first place. Do not ask for advice on what you think is the solution !

Comment: Hello @MGX, I'm trying to ensure that when the user enters the values ​​they are seen in a format where the values ​​in thousands are seen with a point, but the decimals with commas and those values ​​that are entered can be added

Comment: From your example, 11.111.133 is not valid number it should be treated as a string. Now if you want to do an addition you should split it based on the number of decimals you have got and add the corresponding results and finally combine them back again to show them in your format as it will be a string again.

Comment: For example, to add 11.111.133 + 222.222, you should split it like this [11], [111], [113] and [222],[222] and then add [11]+[222], [111]+[222], [111]+[0] assuming that is how your logic works (you can tweak it in any way you like). So this will result in 233.333.111.

Comment: I've added it as my answer. Will also have a look at your next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, `11.111.133` is not valid number it should be treated as a string. Now if you want to do an addition you should split it based on the number of decimals you have got and add the corresponding results and finally combine them back again to show them in your format as it will be a string again.

For example, to add `11.111.133 + 222.222`, you should split it like this `[11], [111], [113]` and `[222],[222]` and then add `[11]+[222], [111]+[222], [111]+[0]` assuming that is how your logic works (you can tweak it in any way you like). So this will result in `233.333.111`.